# Create User Picture Field

Tags: 8

I accidantly deleted the user picture field while development. Now the app is production and a new feature should provide user pictures.

How do I get back the user picture field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the configuration files of the user picture field in the standard profile. You can export the complete config, add the yaml files of the field and reimport again.

Or if you want to import the field in UI, go to *admin/config/development/configuration/single/import*, select the configuration type **Field storage** and import the content of

`core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.storage.user.user_picture.yml`

The same for the configuration type **Field** and the content of

`core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.field.user.user.user_picture.yml`.